# Is there a closed form solution to the Universal Kepler Equation, how about the traditional Kepler equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am under the impression that there is no closed form solution , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation# ,

> Kepler's equation is a transcendental equation because sine is a transcendental function, meaning it cannot be solved for E algebraically. Numerical analysis and series expansions are generally required to evaluate E.

Yet this paper, https://www.scirp.org/html/12-4500390_52772.htm ,

> Combining these new expressions of the universal functions and their identities, we establish one biquadratic equation for universal anomaly  for all conics; solving this new equation, we have a new exact solution of the pre- sent problem for the universal anomaly as a function of the time. The verifying of the universal Kepler’s equation and the traditional forms of Kepler’s equation from this new solution are discussed.

seems to claim otherwise.  The solution to the traditional form of Kepler's equation is given in equations 40 and 41, and I've checked it using MATLAB, starting with e = 0.3, E = 1, Kepler's eq gives M = 0.7476.  Using 40 and 41 to solve the equation given e = 0.3 and M = 0.7476 gives E = 1.0097, which is close :)

I have an MS in math, but the math in Tokis' paper is beyond me. Can anyone clarify the situation?

Tokis' paper is also available as a pdf at https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Solution-of-Kepler%E2%80%99s-Equation-Tokis/c09e592ad648ec24e8796c797a6b2ec33eb36f28

Comment: *which is close :)* Isn’t it supposed to be exact? “Close” doesn’t count. I get the same numbers as you.

Comment: Personally, I am wary of any paper published in a SCIRP journal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look too good to me.

$$$$

[image]

Comment: Yet SemanticScholar says the paper has 10 citations!

Comment: @G.Smith Truly a mystery. Perhaps your wariness is justified :)

Comment: LOL.  Can you comment on the paper generally?  Is it just nonsense?  How did it get published, etc.?

Comment: @DrWill *How did it get published?* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Research_Publishing

Comment: @DrWill There is a kind of symbiosis between misguided scientists/enthusiasts/cranks and predatory journals which publish papers with little to no professional scrutiny in exchange for publishing fees.  The former gain publications and citations to add to their CVs (which may be impressive at a glance, especially to those who don't know any better), and the latter get paid.

Comment: A new solution has just appeared in MNRAS, in a [paper](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-abstract/525/1/57/7220029) claiming that the suggested method renders high accuracy without requiring iteration.